# Appending JavaScript to all pages in JIRA

Tags: javascript, jira

I'm trying to append two JavaScript files to all pages in JIRA, following [this guide](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+JavaScript+to+all+pages+for+Google+Analytics).

However, this only works on the Dashboard page when you login, not on other pages.

Does anyone have a clue why it does not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with a plugin:

1. Define [web resource module](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Web+Resource+Plugin+Module) that will list your .js files you want included.
2. Define [servlet filter module](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Servlet+Filter+Plugin+Module) and use URL pattern to specify which pages you'd like to intercept.
3. In the servlet filter class, use web resource manager to require your web resource module: `ComponentManager.getComponentInstanceOfType(WebResourceManager.class)
   .requireResource("com.whatever.plugin:my-resource");`

Answer (score 0):

There is more easiest way to add javascript shared everywhere in jira.

1. Open Jira Administration - System
2. on the left side find USER INTERFACE section
3. click Announcement Banner

or just simple push . (dot) and write Announcement Banner, push Enter button.